# Capturar URL que esta dentro de uma div com Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Eu tenho um projeto onde tem vários boxes, com uma imagem, e um link. Eu gostaria que quando eu clicasse sobre a class .single-project capturasse o valor do href, mas não estou conseguindo.

```js
$('.single-project').on('click', function() {
  window.location.href = ($(this).attr("href"));
});
```

```html
<div class="single-project">
  <img src="img/project/projeto01.jpg" alt="">
  <div class="project-overly">
    <a href="single-project.html">
      <h3>Titulo</h3>
    </a>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo o que eu entendi você precisa do seguinte código:

```
$('.single-project').on('click', function() {  
   window.location.href = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
});
```

Caso tenha múltiplas URLS

```
$('.single-project').on('click', function() {
  var arr = [];
  $.each($(this).find('a'), function(index,valor){
   arr.push($(valor).attr('href'))
  });
  $('p').text(arr)
});
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, muito obrigado cara

Answer (score 0):

O seu problema consiste no nível do pai da div e o operador this. Coloque a class 'single-project' na tag `<a>` da qual você quer extrair a URL e onde é acionado o click.

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $('.single-project').click(function(){
        alert($(this).attr("href"));
     })
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="outra-class">
          <img src="img/project/projeto01.jpg" alt="">
          <div class="project-overly">
            <a class="single-project" href="www.google.com.br">
              <h3>Titulo</h3>
            </a>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: esse código não vai da certo, a ação que eu quero é quando clicar na caixa .single-project, pois dentro dela tem o link, uma descrição, e uma imagem

Comment: Então você não poderá usar o this. Nesse caso usaria $('a').attr("href")

Comment: desa forma aí ele vai pegar o primeiro link que aparecer no site